# не находится пиксель нужного цвета

Tags: python-3.x, pillow

не находится пиксель цвета (242, 103, 64)

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import os
import time
from pygame import time
from mouse import move
from keyboard import is_pressed
x1 = 0
y1 = 0
ck = time.Clock()
a = False
def screenGrab():
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    return im
while True:
    ck.tick(10)
    if is_pressed('q'):
        im = screenGrab()
        a = False
        for y in range(0, 1079):
            for x in (0, 1919):
                if im.getpixel((x, y)) == (242, 103, 64):
                    x1 = x
                    y1 = y
                    a = True
                    break
            if a:
                break
        move(x1, y1)
```

Comment: значит, нет такого цвета. У меня существующие цвета находит

Comment: Приведите скриншот, в котором вы ищете точку.

Comment: я проверил, этот цвет есть.

Comment: я склонен больше верить результатам кода, который у меня работает, чем вам ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ засуньте в код белый, черный, любой фон и проверьте на работоспособность

Comment: неработает ни с одним цветом.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте передвинуть проверку `a` и поставить перед внутренним циклом:

```
        for y in range(0, 1079):
            if a:
                break
            for x in (0, 1919):
                if im.getpixel((x, y)) == (242, 103, 64):
                    x1 = x
                    y1 = y
                    a = True
                    break
```

У вас получалось, что на эту проверку попадает только после очередного прохождения внутреннего цикла полностью.

Хотя может и не в этом дело.

Comment: тво идея не помогла.